# Can't format partition containing Gpart Live on USB

Tags: windows-7, usb, partitioning

I have Gpart live on a USB and used tuxboot to make it bootable. I'm running Windows 7. The USB is recognized in Windows 7 and I can browse the files using Explorer on the USB. I can also add files onto the USB, but when I try to format using Disk Management I get a "volume is not formattable" error.

The file system on the USB is FAT 16

Answer (score 0):

You're booting from the partition in question, running live, and it's staying mounted the whole time (so you can run programs, etc), right? You can't format a mounted partition, and you can't un-mount it since it's essentially your system drive and always in use.

If you want to format it, you can either boot from a different partition or media, or if you have enough ram (maybe over a gig, varies by distro) and if "Gpart live" will accept the `toram` boot option, you can add that word at boot time to copy all your required system files to ram and run from there. Then you can unmount & format your USB.

Comment: No, I'm not booting from it. I'm in Win 7 and I insert the drive so I can format it.

Comment: Ah, wasn't 100% clear from original Q. I'm not sure why windows wouldn't want to format it, maybe an unsupported or funny format? But gparted (on your USB, or another Mint/Ubuntu) should be able to format just about anything & the `toram` technique should work if you wanted to try it. Or  It's also possible that the whole USB is read-only, maybe from a switch (haven't seen any USB's with switches, but SD cards have them) or an error in the USB